# How do I move variable named files from one directory to another?

Tags: batch-file

Here is what I have so far that doesn't work:

```
set from=V:\directory\CONCA*.*
set to=V:\directory\CONCA
for /f %%a IN ('dir "%from%" /b') do move %from%\%%a %to%
```

This returns the error message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I do not always have a file in the directory that it is from,  I do not want to see any error messages when it does not find a file.

I do want to see what is it moving when it finds something to move.

Comment: Trying `for /f %%a in ('dir "%from%" /b') do ECHO move %from%\%%a %to%` you will see the erroneous syntax on the first line: `move V:\directory\CONCA*.*\CONCA V:\directory\CONCA` etc. Read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
set "from=V:\directory"
set "to=V:\directory\CONCA"
    rem ensure that target folder exists
md "%to%" 2>NUL
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir "%from%\CONCA*.*" /b /A:-D 2^>NUL') do (
    echo "%from%\%%a"
    rem move "%from%\%%a" "%to%\"
)
```

Explanation:

- my comment to your question shows up the quoted error message culprit;
- `2>NUL` [redirect error messages to NUL](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html); we need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#escape) `>` redirection operator when used in a command processed by `for /F` loop as `2^>NUL`;
- `"delims="` to treat possible spaces in file names properly;
- `/A:-D` exclude folders to prevent `move "V:\directory\CONCA"  "V:\directory\CONCA\"` (attempt to move *itself to itself*);
- `echo "%from%\%%a"` to satisfy *I do want to see what is it moving when it finds something to move* claim;
- `rem move "%from%\%%a" "%to%\"` operational `move` command is commented up using `rem` merely for debugging phase: remove `rem` as soon as debugged (but no sooner).